# Karma don't run tests

Tags: jasmine, karma-runner, karma-jasmine

I have default config for karma:

```
    module.exports = function(config) {
    config.set({
    basePath: '',
    frameworks: ['jasmine'],
    files: [
      './app/*.js',
      './app/*.spec.js'
    ],
    exclude: [],
    preprocessors: {},
    reporters: ['progress'],
    port: 9876,
    colors: true,
    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,
    autoWatch: false,
    browsers: ['Chrome'],
    singleRun: false,
    concurrency: Infinity
    })
}
```

My package.json:

```
"name": "app",
"version": "1.0.0",
"description": "",
"main": "index.js",
"scripts": {
  "test": "./node_modules/karma/bin/karma start karma.conf.js"
},
"author": "",
"license": "ISC",
"devDependencies": {
  "jasmine-core": "^2.4.1",
  "karma": "^0.13.21",
  "karma-chrome-launcher": "^0.2.2",
  "karma-jasmine": "^0.3.7",
  "requirejs": "^2.1.22"
}
```

In folder app I have two files, calculator.js:

```
'use strict';

window.calculator = window.calculator || {};

(function() {
    var getIntById = function(id) {
    return parseInt(document.getElementById(id).value, 10);
    };

    var calculate = function() {
    var sum = getIntById('x') + getIntById('y');
    document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = isNaN(sum) ? 0 : sum;
    };

    window.calculator.init = function() {
    document.getElementById('add').addEventListener('click', calculate);
    };
})();
```

and calculator.spec.js:

```
/*
 * Unit tests for lib/calculator.js
 */

describe('Calculator', function() {

  // inject the HTML fixture for the tests
  beforeEach(function() {
    var fixture = '<div id="fixture"><input id="x" type="text">' + 
      '<input id="y" type="text">' + 
      '<input id="add" type="button" value="Add Numbers">' +
      'Result: <span id="result" /></div>';

    document.body.insertAdjacentHTML(
      'afterbegin', 
      fixture);
  });

  // remove the html fixture from the DOM
  afterEach(function() {
    document.body.removeChild(document.getElementById('fixture'));
  });

  // call the init function of calculator to register DOM elements
  beforeEach(function() {
    window.calculator.init();
  });

  it('should return 3 for 1 + 2', function() {
    document.getElementById('x').value = 1;
    document.getElementById('y').value = 2;
    document.getElementById('add').click();
    expect(document.getElementById('result').innerHTML).toBe('3');
  });

  it('should calculate zero for invalid x value', function() {
    document.getElementById('x').value = 'hello';
    document.getElementById('y').value = 2;
    document.getElementById('add').click();
    expect(document.getElementById('result').innerHTML).toBe('0');
  });

  it('should calculate zero for invalid y value', function() {
    document.getElementById('x').value = 1;
    document.getElementById('y').value = 'goodbye';
    document.getElementById('add').click();
    expect(document.getElementById('result').innerHTML).toBe('0');
  });

});
```

Now when I try run test with npm test karma open connection with chrome and open tab, but when I look to devTools and go to source I can't find my calculator.js and spec file.
[image]

Why karma did't execute my spec file?

Comment: First, set the `logLevel` in your karma configuration file equal to `config.LOG_DEBUG`.  This will actually show the files that are being loaded into the browser.